# java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip filein JBOSS Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jboss, tomcat7

When i deploy my *.war file in jboss 4.2 server it says
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file 
but it is working in the tomcat server

### Error LOG

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerSupport.processNestedDeployments(SubDeployerSupport.java:377)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerSupport.init(SubDeployerSupport.java:284)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.init(MainDeployer.java:872)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:809)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy10.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

### JARS in my Web App

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
commons-pool-1.4.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.6.1.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.6.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.1.jar
jasypt-1.6.jar
jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar
jgoodies-common.jar
jgoodies-forms.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
jsp-api.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
org.apache.commons.el_1.0.0.v200806031608.jar
servlet-api.jar
sojo-1.0.0.jar
spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects.jar
spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-build-src-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context.jar
spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-json-1.3.1.jar
spring-orm-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.1.jar
spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
```

---

### MANIFEST.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:

### WEB XML

```
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
              <display-name>MRChartProject</display-name>
              <servlet>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
              </servlet>
                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>
            </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I increased no of open files in the jboss server and now the above error is resolved..  ulimit -n 100000